# Boto3 script to get all the tags from all Lambda functions across all regions for my account

Tags: boto3

Please help -

**Boto3** script to get all the tags from all Lambda functions  across all regions for my AWS account

Comment: Can you share what you tired?

Comment: This is more of a task rather than an issue you are experiencing WHILE developing. It's pretty straightforward and Boto3 documentation should get you there: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Never mind,i am able to do it using AWS cli **get-resources** function.